# missing assembly reference in Aspx scheduler

Tags: c#, asp.net, devexpress

I am trying to learn Devexpress scheduling and while I did their demo code a missing assembly reference error occurred in this namespace

> using DevExpress.Web.Demos;

the code that Itried is

```
    using System;
using System.Web.UI;
using DevExpress.Web.ASPxScheduler;
using DevExpress.Web.Demos;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
public partial class Miscellaneous_DateNavigator : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Init() {
        DemoHelper.Instance.ControlAreaMaxWidth = Unit.Percentage(100);
    }
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        SchedulerDemoUtils.ApplyDefaults(this, ASPxScheduler1);
        SchedulerDemoUtils.ApplyWorkTime(this, ASPxScheduler1);
        DataHelper.SetupDefaultMappings(ASPxScheduler1);
        DataHelper.ProvideRowInsertion(ASPxScheduler1, myDataSource);
        DataHelper.SetupStatuses(ASPxScheduler1);
        DataHelper.SetupLabels(ASPxScheduler1);
        ASPxScheduler1.DataBind();

        ApplyDateNavigatorProperties();
    }

    void ApplyDateNavigatorProperties() {
        DateNavigatorProperties props = ASPxDateNavigator1.Properties;
        props.BoldAppointmentDates = chkBoldAppointmentDates.Checked;
        props.ShowTodayButton = chkShowTodayButton.Checked;
        props.ShowWeekNumbers = chkShowWeekNumbers.Checked;

        ASPxScheduler1.ApplyChanges(ASPxSchedulerChangeAction.NotifyVisibleIntervalsChanged);
    }
}
```

the

> DemoHelper and SchedulerDemoUtils shows the error message

I  googled and asked to their team but didn't get anything. Why it happens?
and how can i solve it

Comment: Are you want to try reproduce a demo example in a new project and which example you're trying to reproduce? The corresponding `DevExpress.Web.Demos` namespace should be exist in `.cs` file of the source demo project, you need to add that file in your own project.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto yes I did . but still it shows error in DemoHelper and SchedulerDemoUtils.

Comment: Is it still throwing the same error even `.cs` file containing `DevExpress.Web.Demos` namespace already included in your own project? You can find `.cs` file containing that namespace in `App_Code\DemoHelpers` folder of the example project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can see you have copied the code snippet from the DevExpress [online demos](https://demos.devexpress.com/asp/Default.aspx): [Scheduling > Date Navigator](https://demos.devexpress.com/ASPxSchedulerDemos/Miscellaneous/DateNavigator.aspx) demo module.
If so, the `DataHelper`, the `DemoHelper` and the `SchedulerDemoUtils` classes which are related to the demo-shell infrastructure should be included in your own project.

According to the [Contol Demos](https://documentation.devexpress.com/AspNet/11900/What-s-Installed/Control-Demos) help article, you can find the related source code locally:

> Solution files (with C# and VB.NET source code) for technical demos
>   are included in the installation – to demonstrate how to use
>   DevExpress controls. Run a solution from the corresponding directory
>   to see the source code for a specific demo
>   ("C:\Users\Public\Documents\DevExpress Demos 17.2\Components...").

SO, take a look at something like `...ASPxScheduler\CS\App_Code\SchedulerDemoUtils.cs` in the sample projects directory. Anyway, I suggest you contact the DevExpress support directly. From my experience, their guys are quite fast and helpful.